# posts_where set only one custom post type using hook

Tags: php, wordpress

in my wordpress pulgin i used the `post_where` filter but it's effect all other post type of my site.

my question is how to set this filter only for `"property"` post only

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where'); 

function posts_where($where)
{
       global $wpdb,$wp_query;
       $where .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="wp_gp_latitude" ';
       $where .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="wp_gp_longitude" ';  

    return $where;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so please provide the code where you are having issues, also your problem / question is rather unclear.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'posts_where', 10, 2);

function posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    global $wpdb,$wp_query;
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'property') {
        $where .= ' AND latitude.meta_key="wp_gp_latitude" ';
        $where .= ' AND longitude.meta_key="wp_gp_longitude" ';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

If you add `$priority = 10 //normal` and `$accepted_args = 2` to your `add_filter` function,
you will have a `$query` object in your `posts_where` function that you can put a conditional on your `post_type` for 'property' to have it only affect your custom post type.

Here is a link to the WP codex documentation for the `add_filter` function:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: this condition work only backend but not get post type in front end